# Trying to multiply two dynamically created matrices(2d vector's) together in c++

Tags: c++, loops, vector, matrix-multiplication, 2d-vector

So what I am trying to do is multiply one 2d vector by another 2d vector.

I come from Java,Python and C# so I am pretty much learning C++ as I go along.

I have the code down to generate the vector and display the vector but I can't seem to finish the multiplication part.

v1 is another matrix that is already generated.

```
vector<vector<int> > v2 = getVector();

int n1 = v1[0].size();
int n2 = v2.size();

vector<int> a1(n2, 0);
vector<vector<int> > ans(n1, a1);

for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            // same as z[i][j] = z[i][j] + x[i][k] * y[k][j];
            ans[i][j] += v1[i][k] * v2[k][j];
        }
    }
}

displayVector(ans);
```

My guess for where I am going wrong is in the inner-most loop. I can't figure out what to actually put in place of that 10 I have there now.

Comment: For matrix mult v1.size() must equal v2[0].size().  That number (same for both matrices) replaces your 10 for k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [multiply matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#General_definition_2), the number of columns of the matrix on the left side must equal the number of rows of the matrix on the right side. You need to check that that is true, and use that common number for your size of the `k` variable:

```
int nCommon = v1.size();
assert(v2[0].size() == nCommon);
for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < nCommon ; k++) {
            ans[i][j] += v1[i][k] * v2[k][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just getting mixed up with that part.

Answer (score 1):

For you inner loop, you should do something like this

```
            ans[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < n2; k++) {               
                ans[i][j] += v1[i][k] * v2[k][j];
            }
```

I don't know where the `10` comes from.

Comment: I just had the 10 in there as a placeholder for now.